# GCP: Is traffic to a VM public IP encrypted within a single region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

I want to use a Cloud Run container that sends HTTP traffic to a Compute Engine VM via public IP address.

Internal IPs are not possible as [Cloud Run does not support VPC](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services#unsupported-services).

Cloud Run is regional which means my container can run in any of the zones in a region.

Is the plain text HTTP traffic I send from the Cloud Run instance to my Compute Engine VM public IP encrypted within a zone, or between zones in a region?

https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-in-transit#end_user_internet_to_a_customer_application_hosted_on_google_cloud

- `VM to VM traffic, using public IP addresses, is not encrypted by default and its security is provided at the user's discretion.`
- This is mentioned for connections from the end user over the internet, but its unclear if plain text traffic between zones is encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

If your traffic is in HTTP, the traffic is not encrypted. However, your tcp packets won't go on the public internet and will stay on Google private network.

The zones in the same region are connected with Google private network and, I'm sure, with a low layer encryption (something like IPSec).

So, now, all depend your concern:

- Is the traffic HTTP traffic encrypted? No
- Is your tcp packet are in plain text on public internet? No
- Is there a low layer transport encryption on Google private network? Yes